# Why changing object type affects Python's behavior on pass-by-reference?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I would have expected the following code:

```
def a(l):
    l.append(3)

def b(l):
    l = 5

def c(l):
    l = (2,-2)

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
a(numbers)
print(numbers)
b(numbers)
print(numbers)
c(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

to print:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
5
(2,-2)
```

but it prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

why??

***EDIT:***

It is because of difference between **pass by reference** and **call by sharing**!

Comment: Maybe you are confusing [*pass-by-reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) with objects being passed **as** references (i.e. in Python, objects are passed *as* reference)?

Comment: In the first case you are passing in a mutable object and mutating it. The other cases you are changing the local name to point to a new value and this does not change the calling scope, you would need to `return l` to return that value back to the calling scope, e.g. `numbers = b(numbers)`

Comment: @AChampion It would still not update the original `l` variable. That would require assigning the return value to the (global) variable.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you are right, would you please specify dfferences between pass by reference and pass as reference?

Comment: Have a look at the article I linked to.

Comment: More specifically for Python: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Comment: @FelixKling and @ AChampion, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The way I view this is that Python, like C and Java, effectively does *pass by value*.  In the case of your `a()` function, you are *passing a reference by value*.  There is no *pass by reference* there.

Perl, on the other hand, does *pass by alias* which has some similar behaviors to *pass by reference*.

I've seen a computer science professor incorrectly claim Objective-C passes by reference because the text book says so, without thinking it through.  But it's still just pass by value.

Answer (score 2):

The first method (`a`) is actually modifying the list item passed via `l.append(...)`

Both the second and third methods (`b` and `c`) *reassign* the parameter `l` to a new value.  This reassignment is local to the function and is not returned, hence it is lost.  When you print `numbers` after executing `b(numbers)` and `c(numbers)`, you are printing the value that was modified by method `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Most values in Python are immutable, which means they cannot be updated. This means that the value of the variable cannot change. However, it is possible to make a reference point to a new (immutable) value. Thus, when writing

```
i = 4
i = 5
```

you are in fact first making `i` point to the (immutable value) 4, then pointing `i` to the (equally immutable) value 5.

Lists, however, are mutable. That means we can do

```
L = [3,4]
L.append(5)
```

and have the same referenced object updated with a new value `[3, 4, 5]`.

When calling a function, the values of e.g. `i` and `L` are not passed directly to the function. Instead references to the values are passed. The original references are saved also in the calling environment, to be restored when the called function returns.

Looking at your functions that means:

```
def a(l):
    l.append(3)
```

Here, the reference `l` is *not* changed/updated, since append will change the value of what is referenced. Thus, when returning from the function `l` will be "restored" to the same value as used in the function, and the list is updated.

```
def b(l):
    l = 5

def c(l):
   l = (2,-2)
```

In these two function however, the reference `l` is made to point to something new, due to the assignment. Thus we have modified the reference itself. Then, when returning, the reference is restored to point to the value used in the calling scope. Therefore, `l` will be the original list again, and the reference value used in the function will be out-of-scope and any value pointed to by that reference will be lost/deleted.

Thus, this is more than just a semantic difference than **called by reference** or **called as reference** or **called by sharing** which has to do with the immutability of types and how references work in Python.

Comment: Good explanation.  Note, however, that it doesn't matter if `l` is reassigned in the first function `a`.  `numbers` will be the same using this modified function: 
```def a(l):
    l.append(3);
    l = 0```

Comment: @Alexander (and others) Yes, you are correct. It has to do with the reference being the same `def a(l): l=[] l.append(3)` would not update the original `l` since we first assign `l` to point to a new variable.

Comment: "When calling a function, the arguments (e.g. i and L) are not passed as values to the function. Instead references to the arguments are passed. However, the original references are saved in the calling environment, to be restored when the called function returns." No. The arguments *are* passed. The arguments *are* references. Every value in Python (the value of every variable and the result of every expression) is a reference. There is no "saving" or "restoring" of anything.

Comment: @newacct I can give you that the arguments _are_ references as a matter of semantics, but  I would like to argue that when calling a function, the current environment, that is the variables, are indeed stored on the stack. They can still be accessed from the calling function, but they are still stored. Then, when returning from the function, the stack is popped, which will restore the original values of the variables.

Comment: @JohanL: A called function receives a copy of the passed values. Passed parameters are local variables in the called function and live in the called function's stack frame. They are *not* accessible from the calling function. The calling function's own variables are in its own stack frame and are not accessible to any other function.

Comment: @newacct Except when using the `global` keyword. But even so, that means that the variables are (or their names) are, at least in a sense, saved, and then restored when the function returns. I insist that it is valid mental model of what is happening. What I can agree to, as I already wrote, is that it is not a _reference to the argument_ that is passed, but a _reference to the value_. This I am happy to make clarify in my answer, but I guess that we would still argue the rest of the post.